# como puedo multiplicar el valor de dos inputs

Tags: javascript, html, variables

quiero multimplicar el valor de dos inputs y con un boton que desarroller la operancion por ejemplo en un input 2 y en otro 9 tambien como le puedo hacer para despues tambien se puedan sumar restar y dividir con otros inputs

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
      <input id="1" type="text">
      <input id="2" type="text">
      <input  class="buton" type="button" id="boton_calc" value="Costo">
      <h1 id="esuma">COSTO</h1>

  </body>

    var m1 = getElementById("1");
    var m2 = getElementById("2");
        <script>
    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("boton_calc");
    boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", res);

    function res() {
        var multi = m1 * m2;
        document.getElementById("esuma").innerHTML=multi;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores.

1. Las variables `m1` y `m2` están fuera de la etiqueta `<script>`.
2. Al declarar las variables `m1` y `m2` te falta la palabra reservada `document` antes de `getElementById`.
3. Cuando vas a realizar la multiplicación, te falta acceder al valor que contiene el campo, en este caso seria `m1.value` y `m2.value`.

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
      <input id="1" type="text">
      <input id="2" type="text">
      <input  class="buton" type="button" id="boton_calc" value="Costo">
      <h1 id="esuma">COSTO</h1>

  </body>

    
  <script>
    var m1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var m2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("boton_calc");
    boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", res);

    function res() {
        var multi = m1.value * m2.value;
        document.getElementById("esuma").innerHTML=multi;
    }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una de las cientos de formas de hacerlo:

```js
function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  
  if (option == "+") {
    result.value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  } else if (option == "-") {
    result.value = parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
  } else if (option == "*") {
    result.value = parseInt(a) * parseInt(b);
  } else if (option == "/") {
    result.value = parseInt(a) / parseInt(b);
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  background-color: #0a84ff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 1em
}

input, select {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%
}

input {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em
}

output {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<form oninput="calc()">
  <input id="a" type="number" value="0">
  <select id="select">
    <option>+</option>
    <option>-</option>
    <option>*</option>
    <option>/</option>
  </select>
  <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
  <output id="result"></output>
</form>
```